# File input in Office Add-in?

Tags: reactjs, office-js, office-addins

I'm developing a PowerPoint Add-in with React using like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/project-quickstart)

I want to add a simple file input to select images like this:

```
 <input type="file" id="fileSelector" name="fileSelector" accept="image/png, image/jpeg" />
```

The input is correctly displayed:

[image]

But when I click on it, nothing happens. It's like disabled. There are no error logs.

Is it possible to select a file from an addin? Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: if you can't click it, I think the problem is related to `CSS`, check the z-index and increase the value of it

Comment: As a debugging step, add this control and see if it works. `<form> <input type="file" id="file" /> </form>`

Comment: @NishargShah I don't think it's a problem related to `CSS`. Visually the button is clicked, I can see how it changes. The problem is that the popup is not displaying.

Comment: @RickKirkham Adding the `<form>` tag has no effect.

Comment: It's not just the `<form>` tag. Also, remove the name and accept attributes and see what happens just as a debugging step.

Comment: @RickKirkham `<form><input type="file" /></form>` This isn't working neither.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Please try to reproduce it in Script Lab. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/develop-overview#exploring-apis-with-script-lab

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is an open issue on the office-js GitHub [page](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/1577) that claims this is an issue when deployed using dev tools `npm start` but is fixed when the add-in is deployed to production.